importing SkopeRules from skrules in python
importing SkopeRules from skrules in python
I get this error

ImportError: cannot import name 'Iterable' from 'collections' (C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\collections_init_.py)) when importing SkopeRules from skope.

This is how implemented it using both anaconda and jupyter notebook in the python environment. I used both anaconda and jupyter.
!pip install skope-rules
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
from collections.abc import Iterable

from skrules import SkopeRules

I was expecting the SkopeRules to be imported successfully.

I don't think it will help here because it is at least installing; however, for a better experience in Jupyter you should not be using the exclamation point in conjunction with install commands. Since 2019 the magic install commands were added to insure the installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running. The exclamation point doesn't do that. So specifically, it should be %pip install skope-rules. See more about the modern %pip install command ...

 here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.  Maybe more importantly, you chose Anaconda/conda as your primary package manager, and so you should be choosing that as the primary way you install things. Not mixing and matching. Only fall back to using pip for cases where there is no ...

 conda recipe. That is not the case here. You actually should be running in your notebook %conda install conda-forge::skope-rules (based on here and the use of the magic install commands.)

This has been posted about here at the skope-rules issues page in the repo. The issue is still open as of writing this. There is a workaround offered there.
The source of the issue seems to be collections.Iterable having moved in Python versions greater than 3.10. It looks like sklearn.externals.six also moved and so the proposed solution is alias the paths, like so:
import numpy as np
import collections.abc
import six
import sklearn
collections.Iterable = collections.abc.Iterable
sklearn.externals.six = six
from skrules import SkopeRules

